# Why am I getting NoneType instead of a match object for this regex?

Tags: python, regex

series is a panda series.

```
regex=r"[A-Z]{3,4}\d?"
def no_fracionario(series):
    lista_ticks1=[]
    for item in series:
        tick=re.search(regex,item)
        lista_ticks1.append(tick.group())
    return lista_ticks1


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-7cd5d3ae178b> in <module>
----> 1 lista_ticks=no_fracionario(codneg)

<ipython-input-94-44ce77e449c1> in no_fracionario(series)
      4     for item in series:
      5         tick=re.search(regex,item)
----> 6         lista_ticks1.append(tick.group())
      7     return lista_ticks1

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: There was no match. Why don't you just use `df['col'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{3,4}\d?)', expand=False)`?

Comment: text sample at least? Also I recommend you to try your regex script online before moving to python using any online service, like: https://pythex.org/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I tested the code for a single item it worked.I'd like to have a list with the stock ticks to use as a filter to remove them from the dataframe.

Comment: @Ghanem the regex is working I've tried it to a single item from the dataset.

Comment: _I'd like to have a list with the stock ticks to use as a filter to remove them from the dataframe._ Can you expand on that?

Comment: @Prune My data is from a 500mb dataset... I don't know how I could post it.

Comment: Again, "minimal, reproducible example": you post only enough to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `re.search` in python, the result is a match object only if it actually found a match, or `None` if it couldn't find one.

For Example, if I did `match = re.search(r'a', 'bbb')`, the value of `match` would be `None` because there is no match for `r'a'` in the string `'bbb'`. If I then try to call `match.group()`, I'd be calling `.group()` on `None`, which would result in an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` because `None` doesn't have a method called `group`.

To avoid your error, you could do this:

```py
regex=r"[A-Z]{3,4}\d?"
def no_fracionario(series):
    lista_ticks1=[]
    for item in series:
        tick=re.search(regex,item)
        if tick is not None:
            lista_ticks1.append(tick.group())
    return lista_ticks1
```

That way, you'd only be calling `.group()` on a real match object (not `None`) when the search successfully found a match of your regular expression.

For more information about regular expressions in python, check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [this useful tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions)